# What is the recommended way to use Azure Boards for a kanban approach?

Tags: kanban, azure-boards

Azure Boards works very well for teams doing scrum. With scrum, iterations work well at task board level.

For kanban, however, the task board's need for iterations makes for kludgy setup of fake iterations.

Does any official guidance exist explaining how to do kanban with Azure Boards?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Kanban with Azure Boards, it makes more sense to use the Backlog board instead if the task boards. The Backlog board is was more customizable and it focusses in the level that is important (assuming your backlog has the items of value). You can decompose the PBI/User story on the cards themselves by adding tasks is tests.

That way you don't need any iterations at all at the sprint level.

Comment: Thank you. The things that we're missing in this approach are around some of the timeline-based visualizations that we get with iterations. For example, the Delivery Plans part of ADO needs things to be in iterations.

Comment: Yups. That's true. If you want to be able to plan in delivery plans, you need iterations. You may be able to use the roadmap extension instead, it works based on dates. Or the FlowViz extension to use monte carlo to forecast.

Comment: Make sure you're running the Delivery Plans preview feature. But I find most of these views very limited and the assume advance bucketing of work into sprints.